# Complex Roots of the Characteristic Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following IVP: $y"+6y'+18y=0$, $y(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$, $y'(\frac{\pi}{2})=6$.

Converting this into a characteristic equation:
$$r^2+6r+18=0$$

Now, solving for r:
$$r=-3\pm 3i$$

When I try to solve for the constants of integration, I get $C_1=0$, $C_2=-2e^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}$.

Plugging all of this in, I get: $y=-2e^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}*e^{-3t}*sin(3t)$, but my homework program says I'm incorrect. Anyone have any idea where I might be going wrong?

Comment: If $C_1$ is the coefficient of the sine term and $C_2$ the coefficient of the cosine term, then your answer is correct. Perhaps the grading program was assuming the opposite. If so, it is not a very good grading program.

Comment: Oh, I just now saw your final answer. It should be $y=-2e^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}e^{-3t}\cos(3t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the form of $y(x)$ is the following:

$$y(x)=e^{-3x}\left(c_{1}\cos(3x)+c_{2}\sin(3x)\right),$$

for two constants $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ to be computed using your initial considitons. Then

$0=y\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=e^{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}\left(c_{1}\cdot\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)+c_{2}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\right)=-c_{2}e^{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}$ and this implies $c_{2}=0$ because:
$$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=-1$$

So, the solution reduces to:

$$y(x)=c_{1}e^{-3x}\cos\left(3x\right)$$

Now take the derivative of $y(x)$ :

$$ y^{\prime}(x)=(-3)c_{1}e^{-3x}\cos(3x)-3c_{1}e^{-3x}\sin(3x) $$

and we evaluate at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get:

$$6=y^{\prime}\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=-3c_{1}e^{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}(-1)$$

then $c_{1}=2e^{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}$ and this finally gives:

$$ y(x)= 2e^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}e^{-3x}\cos(3x),$$

or $$ y(x)=2e^{\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-3x\right)}\cos(3x).$$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: Yes, exactly :) Thank you!

Comment: No problem.-----

Comment: @HectorBlandin I really appreciate the level of detail in mapping out all the steps you've undertaken, but the program is still insisting that this solution is incorrect...

Comment: @TobyTobyo: you can try to verify it with Sage or Wolfram to validate the answer.

Comment: @TobyTobyo: You can with Wolfram alpha. Try following this link to confirm the answer https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B6y%27%2B18y%3D0,+y(pi%2F2)%3D0,+y%27(pi%2F2)%3D6

Comment: @TobyTobyo: Yes, I edit again because the correct solution is $y(x)=2 e^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}e^{-3x}\cos(3x)$

Comment: @HectorBlandin Thank you! This solution worked. I'm looking at your math to try and see where I went wrong. Thanks for putting in so much effort to show each step!

Comment: @TobyTobyo: Your welcome.